# flask-user registration: add one more mail id

Tags: python, email, flask

I am using `flask-user` package for user registration. Once the user clicks on register, by default it will send an email to the users' email. I want to add admin email along with that. Is it possible to customize it?

I found [this](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-User/customization.html#view-functions) but I am not sure how to proceed with that.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After taking help of my colleague, I figured out that this can be done by listening to 'signals' sent by the application. For example:

```
@user_registered.connect_via(app)
def after_user_registered(sender, user, **kwargs):
    msg = Message(subject="A new user registered",
                  body='Some message',
                  recipients=["admin@example.com"])
    mail.send(msg)
```

PS: This I wanted to implement so that admin can get an email whenever a new user is registered. Hope this helps someone :)